# Replace a specific string with conditions in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

We have this string. We need to replace occurrences of `\` (backslash) and `\"` (backslash followed by double quotes) with a dot (`.`) but it should not replace if `\"` (backslash followed by double quotes) is followed by comma (`,`) as is the case at end of value of Id. We are trying to use `replaceAll` as whole payload is quite big.

Input example:

```json
{
"Name":"138.5\" Ultra\violet"
"Id":"\\z\\\\\\\\",
}
```

Output should be:

```
{
"Name":"138.5. Ultra.violet"
"Id":"..z......",
}
```

By using this code, it took care of replacing `\"` and `\` but it also replaced `\"` even when it was followed by comma (`,`). I am assuming that it can be done with a regex but I am not good at regex, so appreciate any help.

```
    newcontent=newcontent.toString().replaceAll(/\\"/, '.')
    newcontent=newcontent.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", ".")
```

Comment: If you're asking for a regular expression in the `groovy` language, why do you add the tag `sap`?

Comment: What's generating invalid Json?

Comment: And what happens when the field isn't followed by a comma, as it's the last item in the object?

Comment: And what happens with `"Id":"Some\",thing"`?  I've got a bad feeling about this...

Comment: @SandraRossi I need to use it on sap platform, hence added it.

Comment: @tim_yates We are receiving it in a response. ideally it should remove \", after some but I don't know if there is a way to identify it whether it is in the value or at the end of it.

Comment: Which "SAP" platform? SAP is the 3rd software company in the world (by total revenue), so which one software among the thousands? Do you mean SAPUI5, SAP B1, etc.? How is it important in the context of the question?

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the `\",` with something `special`, then replace all `\(")` with dots, and then replace the `specials` with `\",` back:

```
String input = /{ "Name":"138.5\" Ultra\violet" "Id":"\\z\\\\\\\\", }/

String output = input.replaceAll( '\\\\",', '@@@' )
                     .replaceAll( '\\\\"?', '.' )
                     .replaceAll( '@@@', '\\",' )

assert output == '{ "Name":"138.5. Ultra.violet" "Id":"..z.......", }'
```